# eclipse An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing external folders". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, ide

I'm using Eclipse Helios.
I get the following error randomly shows in my workspace.

> An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing external folders".
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

[image: eclipse internal error: null pointer exception]

I've tried:
- clean the project using menu Project > Clean ..
- close and reopen workspace
- restart eclipse
but none of these can resolved the problem.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That's definitely a different problem. In my case, the error message shows in popup window instead of console, that's not compile/logic error.

Comment: Look at the .log file in the workspace .metadata folder to see if there is a message there.

Comment: @nametal You're right - I got a bit trigger-happy on the close. I've retracted my vote.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart anyway, does anyone face the same problem?? can you give me the solution, please..

Comment: I have seen that before but it never seems to break anything that I have noticed. My theory is it may have to do with versions of Subclipse prior to 1.7 and the new working copy format. I could be wrong though, I have never been able to track that one down even with the error log view.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it was the old post, this answer will helpful for someone.

Try to close and open the project, refreshed project get fixed the  `NullPointerException` in my case.

Even though error is not getting fixed, close the project -> close eclipse -> open eclipse -> open project may fix your `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have edited the `eclipse.ini` file and set the Java version to the same one used in the project.

This file is in the eclipse folder.